# Поиск числа в коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне из коллекции вытащить только числа:

```java
List<String> string = new ArrayList<>(List.of("s", "45", "4", "w", "-2", "gjg"))
```

Comment: попытаться спарсить каждый элемент в число - если вышло, то ок, если нет - то там не число в тексте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть у вас есть список из строк:

```java
List<String> strings = List.of("s", "45", "4", "w", "-2", "gjg");
```

Создадим вспомогательный метод, который будет переводить строку в число, а если это не удалось сделать, то возвращать `null`:

```java
private static Integer parseIntOrNull(String string) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Теперь создадим список чисел и заполним его, используя метод выше:

```java
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String string : strings) {
    Integer integer = parseIntOrNull(string);
    if (integer != null) {
        integers.add(integer);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```java
System.out.println(integers); // => [45, 4, -2]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но компилятор ругается почему то...

Comment: На какой строчке? Какой текст ошибки?

Comment: В этой строчке: for(String string :strings)

Comment: Unexpected token

Comment: Заведите отдельный вопрос или дополните текущий, приложите ваш код и полный текст ошибки компилятора. Укажите также в вопросе версию Java, которой вы компилируете проект.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить, является ли строка числом при помощи метода `String::matches` и регулярного выражения (достаточно простого для целых чисел `[+-]?\\d+`) вместо того, чтобы парсить строки и отлавливать ненужные исключения.

Также следует заметить, что коллекция должна быть правильно типизирована, например, `List<String>`.

Вопрос о том, чтобы вытащить из коллекции некоторые числа можно решить через фильтр, не затрагивая исходную коллекцию, или же путём удаления "не-чисел" из исходной коллекции.

```java
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(List.of("s", "45", "4", "w", "-2", "gjg"));

// создать новый список строк
List<String> stringNums = strings.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.matches("[+-]?\\d+"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
// [45, 4, -2]

// создать новый список целых чисел
List<Integer> nums = strings.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.matches("[+-]?\\d+"))
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
// [45, 4, -2]

// изменить входной список, удалить не-числа
strings.removeIf(s -> !s.matches("[+-]?\\d+"));
// [45, 4, -2]
```